# how to update query parameters when the data is sent through window.postmessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

Consider in an application, where user search for the question and got some results and when he/she clicks on the result , the result is opened in a pop up.

```
var answerLink = '?route=answer&aid=12345';
var answerWindow  = window.open(answerLink, 'detailPage');
```

Now my pop up window is open. And user clicks on second answer . To get the content to be reloaded i am using window.postmessage to send the data but what i obeserved the document.location remain same , i need to modify the aid value with 34567 , is there a way where we can update the aid parameter without reloading the page (?route will reload the page).

Comment: **answerWindow.opener.aid** may help you. that you can get updated value from parent window.

Comment: @AnuragDadheech thanks